# How to write a query against one table which gives unique value from "pm_process_guid"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I would like to write a query against one table which gives unique value from "pm_process_guid" for one ticket, along with all associated values in Assigned Group,  Assigned User and Time on a column wise. How can I write a query in order to get a output like below?

```
pm_process_guid Assign Serial Number    Assigned Group  Assigned User              Time
2E2A9A43-9607-4FCB-B3A7-550440823B20    1   APAC    Ram     3/23/2016 15:06
2E2A9A43-9607-4FCB-B3A7-550440823B20    2   AM      Raj     3/23/2016 15:06
2E2A9A43-9607-4FCB-B3A7-550440823B20    3   APAC    Sree    3/23/2016 15:06
```

I‌ need to get an output like below,

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
pm_process_guid TotalAssign Count   1st Group   1st User         Time          2nd  Group   2nd User         Time   3rd Group   3rd User         Time
2E2A9A43-9607-4FCB-B3A7-550440823B20    3                   APAC    Ram 3/23/2016             15:06               AM     Raj    3/23/2016      15:06            APAC    Sree    3/23/2016      15:06          
‌‌
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is a bit different to other sites on the web, in that readers really appreciate an initial attempt at the problem, through the use of existing resources, like official documentation and search engine research. Would you be able to make an attempt at this, and show us how far you get? Readers are often keen to ensure that they are not merely being given someone else's work.

Answer (score 0):

here is the sample syntx on how to do it.

```
SELECT  pm_process_guid,
        count(*),
        [1st User] = MAX(CASE WHEN AssignSerial = 1 THEN AssignUser END),
        [2nd User] = MAX(CASE WHEN AssignSerial = 2 THEN AssignUser END),
        . . . 
FROM    yourtable
GROUP BY pm_process_guid
```